# Match multiple occurances of regular expressions in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to match multiple occurrances of a regular expression in a string for example, I wanna know if my string contains multiple url and I want to get a usable result like an array:

```
"hey check out http://www.example.com and www.url.io".match(new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?([^ ])+"))
```

would return:

```
["http://www.example.com","www.url.io"]
```

```js
console.log("hey check out http://www.example.com and www.url.io".match(new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?([^ ])+")))
```

and maybe there is a better way to match urls but i didn't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following RegEx:

```
/(http?[^\s]+)|(www?[^\s]+)/g
```

**Demo:**

```js
function urlify(text) {
  var urlRegex = /(http?[^\s]+)|(www?[^\s]+)/g;
  return text.match(urlRegex);
}

console.log(urlify("hey check out http://www.example.com and www.url.io"));
```